# ヘルパー関数について。

Tags: javascript, java

ヘルパー関数とはどういったものでしょうか。
自分自身、JavaやJavaScriptの経験があり、JavaやJavaScriptのコードを例にヘルパー関数について理解を深めたいのですが説明しているサイトがなかなか見つからないです。

Comment: どういうことをしていて「ヘルパー関数」という言葉に出会いましたか？

Comment: 一般的には（主機能を実現する）主関数から呼び出される補助関数のことだと思います。

Comment: 特定の処理、特定の関数だけから使う作業用の関数、他の処理からは使われないもの、というニュアンス込みで補助関数に賛成。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36847/ でオイラが回答に書いた Sugar みたいな奴。でもやっぱりどういうコンテキストで使われていたかで違いそうですね。