# c++ friend関数とfriendクラスの違いを知りたいです。

Tags: c++

c++の参考書で「friend関数はthisポインタを持たない、そのクラスに所属しているわけではない、非公開メンバにアクセスできる。
タイトル通り friend関数とfriendクラスの違いについて教えて欲しいです。

```
int main(){
    Date a(4),b(3);
    Date c = test(a,b);
}

class Date {

private:        
    //double d;
    int x;
    int z;
    static int prst;//静的記憶域期間

public:
    Date();

    Date(int x);

    void print();
    //////////////////////////////////
    friend  Date test(const Date& a, const Date& b)//friend関数
    {
        return Date(a.x + b.x);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////
    int y = 0;
    static int pust;//静的記憶域期間

    void pri(int x);
    static void pri_st(int x);
};
```

Comment: 編集時にプログラムの部分を選択した状態で`{}`をクリックするときれいにハイライトされますので参考にしてください。「ここにコードを入力」は追記が必要ならそのコードを、不要であれば削除してもらうと誤解が減ると思います。

Comment: 質問を投げるだけで放置せず、解決したのであれば[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)し、解決していないものについては質問内容を補足し何を尋ねたいのかを明確にしてください。

Comment: 個人の感想ですが、編集前の「friendの使いみち」のほうが興味深い質問ですね。friend関数とfriendクラスの違いは調べればすぐわかることなので。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

書かれているとおり `friend` 関数は「非メンバなのに `private` `protected` なメンバを直接使うことを認める」ためのものです。適切に OOAD (Object-Oriented Analysis and Design) ができていればまず使うことは無い / 使う必要が無いものです。
使うとしたら「非メンバ関数」として実装するしか手が無い関数を使う場合とか。

自作複素数クラス `class mycomplex` を実装して `double + mycomplex` ができるような演算子を実装したくなったら、左辺が組み込み型なので非メンバ関数な `operator+` が必要となり

```
class mycomplex {
    double re; // real part
    double im; // imaginary part
public:
    mycomplex(double r0=0.0, double i0=0.0) : re(r0), im(i0) { }
    mycomplex(const mycomplex& rh) : re(rh.re), im(rh.im) { }
    // double + mycomplex を行う非メンバ関数 (static メンバでもない)
    friend mycomplex operator+(double lh, const mycomplex& rh) {
        return mycomplex(lh+rh.re, rh.im);
    }
    // 普通に (non-static な) メンバ関数 mycomplex+mycomplex
    mycomplex operator+(const mycomplex& rh) const {
        return mycomplex(this->re+rh.re, this->im+rh.im);
    }
};
```

こんな形で「非メンバな関数」の中で `private` なメンバを直に使うことができます（この `mycomplex` 中で `re` や `im` が `private` としていることが適切かどうかはまた別問題なのでいまはおいておく）
 # そうしている意図は、将来、内部実装を極座標表示にするかもってことなわけだけど

`operator` 以外であっても、フレームワークやライブラリの実装上の都合で非メンバ関数を使わざるを得ないような場合に `friend` 関数を使うことがあるでしょう。
[class メンバー関数をコールバックとして渡したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36847/)

組み込み系だと、開発ツールが割り込みハンドラを [c](/questions/tagged/c) 関数として自動生成してしまったりするので `friend` 関数の出番がままあったりします。

`friend` クラスのほうは「使ったら設計ないしは実装に失敗している」レベルで使い道が無くて、オイラも実用したことはありません。

`friend` は `class` が隠している内面をもろにさらけ出す（オイラは｢臓物を晒す」と称しています）ので、必要の無いところで使うことは禁じ手です。逆に、必要ならためらい無く使いましょう。そういう機能があればより性能が出せるという場面では、あぶない機能でも使えるというのが [c](/questions/tagged/c) や [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) の言語設計方針なので、取捨選択するのはユーザの責任です。

Comment: つまりC,C++では普段は使わない識別子や危険な物もあって使うときに選択して使うってことですかね？

Comment: そのコメントは 44260 スレの誤爆でしょうか？それともここ 44299 スレでの話？本当にこちら44299 スレであれば `friend` は原則使わない、が正解です。どうしても必要な場合に、関数１つだけを `friend` にしてうまくいくのであれば `friend` 関数を使うのはよくある話です。実装上の都合でどうしても `class` レベルで `friend` にしなければならないのであれば `friend class` も使うことがあるかもしれません。が、オイラなら `friend class` を使うよりはリファクタリングを選ぶでしょう、ってことで。もし 44260 スレの話であるならそちらでどうぞ。

Comment: C は、広く使われている言語の中では最古の部類のものです。そのため、最近の言語、たとえば Java や C# では言語設計段階で意図的に削除された危険な機能もいっぱい残っています。それを使うか使わないかはプログラマの選択次第っすね。選択するためにはその機能が危険なのかそうでないのかをプログラマが習得しておかなければなりません。そういう意味で 2018 年現在では C は入門向きではないといわれています。逆に、熟達者が性能を意識して作ったプログラムは、他言語より高速に動くことが多いともいわれています。 C++ は C との互換性を大事にしているのでその辺の事情は同じです。

Answer (score 0):

まず、friend関数とfriendクラスの違いは関数とクラスの違いだけです。
ところで、当初の質問内容はfriendの意味だったと思うのですが、それも一般的な回答は検索で見つかると思います。

さて、大昔の自分もfriendの利用シーンがなかなか思いつかなかったのですが現在は下に述べる部分で使用しています。

(1)friend関数の利用シーン
OSないしシステム側がコールバック関数(C言語の関数)を要求する場合に、直接クラスメンバ関数を渡せないのでfriend関数に橋渡しをしてもらう場合等に使ってます。

(2)friendクラスの利用シーン
非公開のコンストラクタ(デストラクタ)しか持たないクラスAが、Aの配列クラス等に生殺与奪を任せたい場合等に使ってます。派生させればどこでも構築できてしまう場合もありますが、それをやってはいけませんという意味を表現しているつもりです。

以上、具体的な事例もなんらかの役にたつかもしれませんので経験上の一例をあげてみました。